# Checking the elements of a list for multiple strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a list:

```
['[name]\n', 'first_name,jane\n', 'middle_name,anna\n', 'last_name,doe\n', '[age]\n', 'age,30\n', 'dob,1/1/1988\n']
```

How could I check if the strings `'jane'`, `'anna'` and `'doe'` are **ALL** contained in an element of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each name you can use `any` to see if it is contained in any of the strings in the list, then make sure this is true for `all` of the names

```
>>> data = ['[name]\n', 'first_name,jane\n', 'middle_name,anna\n', 'last_name,doe\n', '[age]\n', 'age,30\n', 'dob,1/1/1988\n']
>>> names = ['jane', 'anna', 'doe']
>>> all(any(name in sub for sub in data) for name in names)
True
```